# If I change the base class that a Java Exception class extends, do I need to update the serialVersionUID value?

Tags: java, exception, serialization, serialversionuid

Consider the following Java exception classes:

```
public class BarException extends RuntimeException {
    // [...]
}

public class FooException extends BarException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5322002268075295537L;

    // [...]
}
```

If I wish to update the inheritance hierarchy to remove `BarException`, such that `FooException` derives directly from `RuntimeException`, does this require a change to the `serialVersionUID` value?

```
// FooException with updated inheritance hierarchy
public class FooException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = ???;

    // [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the specification is unclear enough to cause confusion and debate, with no clear answer emerging, the only option left is to trust empirical evidence.

Taking the examples from the question above, of `FooException` deriving from `BarException` deriving from `RuntimeException`, and then removing `BarException` from the inheritance chain, I put together a sample application to try serialization and de-serialization in various combinations.

I get the following results:

**As long as I keep the `serialVersionUID` unchanged, I can successfully serialize and deserialize the original `FooException` as the updated `FooException`, *and* vice versa.**

The following caveats apply:

- I am using JDK 1.5.0_07, and have not tried this on any other versions.
- `FooException` has members of type `int` and `Exception`, which are successfully deserialized.
- `BarException` adds no additional members to `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. "Moving classes up or down the hierarchy" will cause incompatibility with previous serialized instances, as per the [serialization spec](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678).

Answer (score 2):

The [Java 1.5 Serialization Specification](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/version.html#6678) suggests that removing classes from the inheritance hierarchy is a compatible change, so a change to `serialVersionUID` should not be required.

Any extra information in the serialization stream pertaining to `BarException` would be ignored when deserializing to the new `FooException` (which is derived directly from `RuntimeException`).

Comment: You're probably referring to the "Removing classes" point, but I think that only covers completely removing classes, not removing them from inside the inheritance tree while keeping subclasses - it's a case of "Moving classes up or down the hierarchy"

Comment: There is in a method for handling reading an object with a missing class - `readObjectNoData`.

Comment: I'm not sure that the spec is entirely consistent. Deleting a field is not okay, but an entire class is?

Comment: It's a bit strange - removing a class necessarily means removing or changing all fields using that type. And I can't find "changing a (non-primitive) field's type" in either the compatible or the incompatible list.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, but it depends on whether your system persists serialized objects and if you control how the new, refactored code is deployed.

If you don't do persistence and you will refresh the entire deployment with the new version of the code, I don't see the need to change the `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: Hi Steve. As noted in the update to my question, "As long as I keep the serialVersionUID unchanged, I can successfully serialize and deserialize the original FooException as the updated FooException, and vice versa." This change does not seem to break serialization compatibility, so even if the system is persisting serialized objects, and I don't refresh the entire deployment at once, should I still change the serialVersionUID?

Comment: Short answer is I'm unsure - why not test it?  I find the standard Java serialization brittle and it wouldn't surprise me if this worked (or even if it didn't)!